# Modify ellipse equation

Tags: conic-sections

How can one modify an ellipse equation with a Gaussian function to get a new ellipse with bump and/or valley?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant how to stretch out ellipses, I think you could change the circle formula x²+y²=1 to something like (x/2)²+y²=1. Then it would be bigger to the sides, I think.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).